# What's the process in rectangular form for deriving $(a+bi)^{a+bi}$?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, euler-mascheroni-constant

What's the process, using Euler's Formula, solving $(a+bi)^{a+bi}$ when outlined algebraically in rectangular form?

Edit:
And also solving this in the same form and process, $(d cos(y)+i d sin(y))^{(d cos(y)+i d sin(y))}$, where $d = e^x$

Answer (score 2):

$(a+bi)^{(a+bi)}=e^{\log((a+bi)^{(a+bi)})}=e^{(a+bi)\log(a+bi)}$ with $\log(a+bi)=\ln|a+bi|+i*\arg(a+bi)$ when sometimes $\arg(a+bi)=\arctan(b/a)$ depending on the direction of the vector. Note that the outcomes of the log is multivalued, since the log of a complex number is multivalued. The second part you just write $d(\cos(y)+i\sin(y))=d*e^{y}=e^{x+y}$ and solve like above with using some logarithms and power product- and summation rules.

Comment: And what are the vector direction guidelines used to define if  $arg(a+bi)=arctan(b/a)$? As this is for a program which graphs the real and imaginary parts of the equation starting from 0 to infinity.

Comment: The argument means the angle $a+bi$ is making with the real axis where the angle is standardly like: $-\pi<\arg(a+bi)\leqslant\pi$. Argument with a lower case 'a' is multivalued, so you put $+k*2i\pi$ after having calculated the angle. You should draw the vector (a,b) in the complex plane and make a perpendicular porjection on the real axis. By doing that you can determine what lengths the triangle (enclosed by real axis, perpendicular projection and vector) sides are. With that you can compute/determine the angle with the inverse tangent (which also has an equation:-)

Comment: Most of the time in books the angle will be easy to compute, otherwise you can leave the arctan in your answer because it always has a numerical value anyways.

Answer (score 0):

$a+bi = \rho e^{\theta i}\\
(a+bi)^{a+bi}(\rho e^{\theta i})^{a+bi}\\
(\rho^a e^{a\theta i})(\rho^{bi}e^{-b\theta})\\
(\rho^a e^{a\theta i})(e^{(b\ln\rho)i}e^{-b\theta}\\
\rho^ae^{-b\theta}e^{(a\theta + b\ln\rho i)}\\
\rho^ae^{-b\theta}(\cos(a\theta + b\ln\rho) + i\sin(a\theta + b\ln\rho)\\
$

Comment: What is the variable p defined as?

Comment: $\rho = \sqrt {a^2 +b^2}$

Answer (score 0):

$$ z=a+bi = r e^{i\theta}$$ in its polar form.

$$ (a+bi)^{a+bi}=    r e^{i\theta (a+bi)}= r e^{-b\theta +i a\theta}=$$

$$r e^{-b\theta}(\cos a\theta + i \sin a\theta)$$